# Spring REST upload file to amazon

Tags: spring, rest, amazon-web-services

I am receiving the file in my REST API, and want to upload it to AWS (amazon web services). But I don't know how to get the path of this image, and which path of this image I should get. (check please the 3rd block of code provided here)

**Here is my code:**

S3Services interface:

```
public interface S3Services {
    void downloadFile(String keyName);
    void uploadFile(String keyName, String filePath);
}
```

S3ServicesImpl:

```
@Override
public void uploadFile(String keyName, String uploadFilePath) {

    try {
        File file = new File(uploadFilePath);
        s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, file));
        logger.info("===================== Upload File - Done! =====================");

    } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
        logger.info("Caught an AmazonServiceException from PUT requests, rejected reasons:");
        logger.info("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
        logger.info("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
        logger.info("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
        logger.info("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
        logger.info("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
    } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
        logger.info("Caught an AmazonClientException: ");
        logger.info("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Finally, I have my REST method to get the photo:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
    String name = "test11";
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            //convert multipartFile to File
            File fileToUpload = multipartToFile(file);
            s3Services.uploadFile("filename.png", ?????);
            return "You successfully uploaded " + name + " into " + name + "-uploaded !";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
    }
}
```

**My questions are:**

`s3Services.uploadFile("filename.png", ?????);`?

I get the image in my REST method and I would like to upload directly this file, but I have to provide the path of the image which I don't have.

Can I upload the file directly without having it's path?

If I can not upload the file directly, How could I perform the file upload? How and where should I store the image?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Isn't `fileToUpload` a `File` and hence can be plugged into `uploadFile`?  Also where does `S3Service` come from?

Comment: It was my attempt to make the change, but it did not work, I will update now the question back to String. S3Service is an interface, which is implemented  in S3ServicesImpl. I am using the aws-java-sdk

Comment: Well in the AWS SDK, `AmazonS3Client` has a `putObject` that takes `String` content. Why not just use that?